# module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'get_channel'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

As the title suggests, I am getting the error `AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'get_channel'`My current code is:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

    @commands.command(name="announce")  # Announce Command
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def announce(self, ctx, *args):
        user = ctx.author
        response = ""
        for arg in args:
            response = response + " " + arg
        await ctx.channel.send("Announcing...")
        chan = commands.get_channel(defs.chan_announcements())
        await chan.send(response)
```

Not really sure what to do about this.

Comment: Another approach is using `ctx.guild.get_channel(defs.chan_announcements())`

Answer (score 0):

get_channel() is a method from discord.Client or discord.ext.commands.Bot

Reference [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel).

Comment: So I have to start it as `@bot.command()`?

Comment: you can call it as `commands.Bot.get_channel(defs.chan_announcements())`